# Python Lists and list-like types

Tags: python, encoding, programming-languages, python-multiprocessing

Please what function takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space with *and* inserted before the last item.

Answer (score 0):

I could only think of something a bit hacky.

```
value_list = [bar, foo, baz]
value_string = str(value_list)
value_string[len(value_list[-1])-1] = " and "
```

What this does is converting the list to a string and then replacing the last comma with an `and` since the last comma is located before`[-1]` the last word `value_list[-1]`

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If "lst" is your list and your values have a str method then the following works (for small inputs).

```
", ".join(map(str, lst[:-1])) + " and " + str(lst[-1])
```